# CakePHP 3 Find records that have no associated record (hasMany)

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0, has-many

I have `Products hasMany Tasks`.

What is the the best way to find all products that do not have an associated record in the tasks table?

I've tried with:

```
$query->matching('Tasks', function ($q) {
return $q->where(['Tasks.product_id' => NULL});
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: If you're using 3.1 or higher, [notMatching](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching) might be the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice you to use **Subqueries**

It's the simplest way to to find all Products that do not have an associated record ..
Try this :

```
    $matchingTasks= $this->Products->association('Tasks')->find()
        ->select(['product_id'])// id of product in Tasks Table
        ->distinct();

    $query = $this->Products->find()
        ->where(['id NOT IN' => $matchingTasks]);
    // to debug the result
      foreach($query as $product){
        debug($product);
    }
    die();
```

Comment: i am wonder if there is a shorter command for this task since in mysql its only 3 lines:
SELECT * FROM `Products`
Left Outer JOIN `Products` ON Products.id=Task.product_id
where products.id IS null

Answer (score 5):

As Greg Schmidt wrote: [notMatching](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-notmatching) is the solution:

```
$query = $articlesTable->find()->notMatching('Tags');
```

or

```
$query = $articlesTable
->find()
->notMatching('Tags', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Tags.name' => 'boring']);
});
```